# Is it possible to render lines between scatter plot points in c3?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am using C3 for rendering the charts. Is it possible to render the three graphs except the first one. First one I implemented using Scatter chart. But I am not able to find a way to create the line between the points in second and third charts. Can anyone suggest me a method to do render the second, third and the last chart?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can somebody tell me the name of the 3rd chart? First one in the second row.